# What time are XBLA games released?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

EST/PST? Are they released at the same official time each Wednesday, or does it vary? If it does, what time are they generally released? Looking for a definitive source.

Comment: IS it safe to assume you are asking in regards to Fez?

Comment: If it happens to be Fez you're asking about, it's out now, 7AM EST.

Comment: this is a great way to ask a question in the general form that will be useful for much longer. Kudos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_Live_Arcade_games#Released.2Fdelisted_games) it seems a vast majority of the games were released on Wednesdays, at least for the sampling of about 10 released in 2012 that I checked.  I do note that this is not an absolute rule, as a game ironically named "Anomaly: Warzone Earth" was released on April 6th, 2012 - a *Friday*.  Unless that is an error, which would in turn be even more ironic.

From [Major Nelson's blog](http://majornelson.com/category/marketplace/arcade/) it appears that he posts updates about Arcade games around ~6 AM PST on release days most of the time.  I think this is about the best info you are likely to get and there's no way to be sure it will stay that way.  Also note that all games state "Check availability in your Xbox Live region", which means that while this info is probably accurate for US, times may vary by hours or days for other regions.

Comment: Fridays have become a new thing lately. The Simpsons Arcade was on Friday as well, and now FEZ is Friday.

Comment: Friday, _the 13th_. (It's an occasion.)

Answer (score 0):

I usually check Wednesday for new games. They are not released in the morning, but usually when I check between Wed 12PM-2PM PST they are released. Don't know if this varies by region though.

Answer (score 0):

XBLA games are usually released 12:00 PM UK time (GMT 0) and are available after that.

If you live in the States, i would expect the time to be around 12:00 PST but im not as sure as the Europe timing.

Some games may be released on other days of the week, (such as the game FEZ which was released last friday)

Hope i was some kind of help and cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are able to download games from the Xbox website before you can download them from the marketplace on the console. I tend to check at about 11AM, that's when they seem to be available.

Answer (score -1):

I have actually called Microsoft to find out what time the Resident Evil 4 HD would be released, and was told "at some point during the release date".  My buddy that keeps the sleep schedule of an owl told me that he was able to buy it at 4 AM CST on its release date, but have heard generally between midnight and 6 am depending on time zones among many other undisclosed factors.